# Angular UI-Bootstrap Typeahead with object literal structure

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is is possible to use Angular UI-Bootstrap Typeahead with the following data? This data is a representation of a wordpress taxonomy with format term_id : term_name

```
$scope.domainFields = {
    "304": "Administration et secr\u00e9tariat",
    "305": "Arts, m\u00e9dias et divertissement",
    "306": "Assurance",
    "307": "Comptabilit\u00e9 et finance"
    //...
};
```

**View:**

I am using Angular-xeditable typeahead which implements Angular-ui typeahead.

currentUser.field contains the current term_id, how to loop through domainFields object in e-typeahead and display the current term_name associated with term_id?

```
<a href="#"
   editable-text="currentUser.field"
   e-typeahead="
   term_id as term_name for field in domainFields
   | filter:$viewValue 
   | limitTo:8">
{{ domainFields[currentUser.field] || 'empty' }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (key, value) in your object while specifying repeating array in `e-typeahead`

**Markup**

```
<a href="#"
   editable-text="currentUser.field"
   e-typeahead="
   term_id as term_name for (term_id, term_name) in domainFields
   | filter:$viewValue 
   | limitTo:8">
{{ domainFields[currentUser.field] || 'empty' }}
</a>
```

Comment: Hi, it gives error Error: Expected typeahead specification in form of "_modelValue_ (as _label_)? for _item_ in _collection_" but got "term_id as term_name for (term_id, term_name) in domainFields | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8".

Comment: @ericsicons I think this issue is already solved here https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3350